# Saving data in ruby on Rails without resources

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Its bit difficult for me to explain what I want, but still I will try my best.

I created a form in Rails where user can fill certain fields. Now once these fields are filled, I know that I can use resources in Router and define a create method in Controller that will save the data to database.
However what I want is to pass data saved in the form to my controller. Then create a custom method in controller that will be just like traditional Create method, but instead of passing parameters using Resource method, I want to pass them as parameter. Is it even possible in Rails:

This is my current View to create form:

```
<h1> Please add a new product</h1>
<%= form_for @product do |p| %>
  <p>
    <%= p.label 'Product Name' %><br/>
    <%= p.text_field :product_name %><br/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= p.label 'Description' %><br/>
    <%= p.text_area :description %><br/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= p.label 'Price' %><br/>
    <%= p.text_field :price %><br/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= p.label 'Rating' %><br/>
    <%= p.text_field :rating %><br/>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

So may be I am using In Built form in Ruby, but I just want to pass parameters from View to Controller's method.

Thanks for help !!!

Comment: Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. You can always define custom routes like `post '/latest_products' => 'products#latest_create'`

Answer (score 1):

I will help you in solving your problem.
Follow these steps:

1. Create your route in routes.rb:

   ```
   get "/create_product" => 'products#create_product', as: :create_product
   ```

   or if you want to pass params through post method:

   ```
   post "/create_product" => 'products#create_product', as: :create_product
   ```
2. Now change your view file according to the new route helper:

   ```
   form_for (@products, url:{:controller=>'products', :action=>'create_product'}, html:{method:'post'})
   ```
3. Now the last step modify your controller:

   ```
   def create_product
    #your form values are avaible here in params variable
    pp params
    puts params[:Price]
    #save your params into ur db
   end
   ```

Note: I assumed that you already have product.rb model